# Cell variable defined in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

When use pylint to check my code, I have `W0640: Cell variable job defined in loop (cell-var-from-loop)`.

**NOTE: Please don't make it as duplicate before you read item2, most of the post is related to the closure or something like in the item2, my concern is on item1.**

**1.** What **can't understand** is: the execution is correct unlike the `item 2` I mentioned next.

**a.py:**

```
jobs = [1, 2]
for job in jobs:
    def fun():
        print(job)
    fun()
```

**pylint:**

```
$ pylint a.py
a.py:4:14: W0640: Cell variable job defined in loop (cell-var-from-loop)
```

**execution:**

```
$ python3 a.py
1
2
```

**2.** What I **can understand** is the warning in next code. The `job` in `fun` hold a reference of the one in `for job in jobs`. Then `fun` not executed at once, so when the `fun` starts run, both `fun` in `all_funcs` will hold the reference of outer `job`, that is `2`. This could be verified when execute next code.

**b.py:**

```
all_funcs = []
jobs = [1, 2]
for job in jobs:
    def fun():
        return job
    all_funcs.append(fun)

for all_func in all_funcs:
    print(all_func())
```

**pylint:**

```
$ pylint b.py
b.py:5:15: W0640: Cell variable job defined in loop (cell-var-from-loop)
```

**execution:**

```
$ python3 b.py
2
2
```

**3.** What I **can understand** is to use next code to fix above issue which now the `job` in the `fun2` holds the value.

**c.py:**

```
all_funcs = []
jobs = [1, 2]
for job in jobs:
    def fun2(job):
        def fun():
            return job
        return fun
    all_funcs.append(fun2(job))

for all_func in all_funcs:
    print(all_func())
```

**pylint:**

```
No W0640 warning.
```

**execution:**

```
$ python3 c.py
1
2
```

**Question:**

As in `item2`, pylint definitely find a bug with that warning. So I wonder if possible I missed any potential issue in `item1` although the execution is correct?

Comment: But, why defining `fun` inside the loop and not outside ?

Comment: @azro This is a minimal of my problem. In fact there is another function wraps all the code. With this internal function, I can directly reference the variable in the external function without explicitly pass them to inner function as arguments.

Comment: "So I wonder if possible I missed any potential issue in item1 although the execution is correct?" Missed what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to understand why the data output in **item 1** is correct and in **item 2** it is not, you can check the addresses of the variables that are displayed on the screen

**Since you are calling fun() immediately, the variable `job` will not change before the fun() complete execution , so you can safely ignore the warning.**

**item 1**

```
jobs = [1, 2]
for job in jobs:
    def fun():
        print(hex(id(job)))
        print(job)
    fun()
```

output: as you can see the **addresses are different**

and the variable `job` points to different objects with each iteration of the loop

```
0x1ee8cb400f0
1
0x1ee8cb40110
2
```

**item 2**

**Unexpected result due to delayed call of executable object**

```
all_funcs = []
jobs = [1, 2]
for job in jobs:
    def fun():
        print(hex(id(job)))
        return job
    all_funcs.append(fun)

for all_func in all_funcs:
    print(all_func())
```

output: unlike **item 1** here the addresses are the same

and the variable `job` points to the same object with each iteration of the loop

```
0x1ee8cb40110
2
0x1ee8cb40110
2
```

also if we change the code a little

```
all_funcs = []
jobs = [1, 2]
for job in jobs:
    def fun():
        print(hex(id(job)))
        return job
    all_funcs.append(fun)

job=5

for all_func in all_funcs:
    print(all_func())
```

output

```
0x1ee8cb40170
5
0x1ee8cb40170
5
```

To summarize everything written above, **pylint** warns you about a **possible** error or a **possible** unexpected result, and forces you to pay attention to this snippet of code

Comment: Thanks. But, I'm not asking why the execution output is different. I'm asking why pylint give warning for item1. Any potential risk for item 1?

Comment: I could directly disable the warning, YES. But as pylint already reported this issue, I don't have confidence to directly disable the warning for item1.

Comment: Since you are calling fun() immediately, the value of job will not change before the fun() complete execution , so you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: So, you think it's a pylint bug? I will talk with pylint team before back to this post.

Comment: This is not an error this is a warning that unexpected results are possible as in item 2

Comment: @atline pylint is giving you a warning **because "Cell variable job defined in loop"**. What is it you don't understand, exactly?

Comment: @atline pylint is often not correct. The warnings are *warnings*, they aren't guarantees. Your question isn't really well specified. What amounts to "proof"? In any case, why not just use a factory function, if the warning bothers you so much?

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of `hex(id(job))` is. It seems redundant

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `hex (id (job))` is required to understand that the `job` object is changes every time, at every step of the loop

Comment: @arutar um, no it isn't. Those objects are created *once*, here: `jobs = [1, 2]`, although, technically in CPython, those objects *exist when the interpreter starts up*, but that is an implementation detail

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, points to a different object every time, every step of the loop